# MongoDB - Embed document with _id into the child

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a document that represents a store with your advertisements as follows:

```
{name: "name of store",
 address: "address of store",
 advertisements: [{title: "title of advertising", desc: "desc of advertising"}]
}
```

To increase read speed and insert or find an advertising from this store is easy but, to delete a specific advertising, how can I do this?

There is a way to add a _id field into the element inside advertisements array? This way, I could find a specific item by _id.

I don't like the approach that use $elemMatch to find an item by your name or other field that isn't de _id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With embedded documents there are no `_id` fields, these are a property of the main document in the collection. There is a full explaination here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

Any embedded documents or array elements or even documents within arrays are stored exactly as is, an in the natural form of how you would work with JSON structures or very close to most dynaminc language native representations.

In your case for documents within an array you can either use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) query operator to find the document(s) you wish to remove.

```
{ name: "<matching name>", advertisements: { $elemMatch: { title: 'title of advertising'  } } }
```

Alternately there is the dot notation approach:

```
{ name: "<matching name>", advertisements.title = 'title of advertising' }
```

Or even index notation:

```
{ name: "<matching name>", advertisements[0] }
```

At any rate there are a collection of [Array operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) for use in updates so you can manipulate the elements.

Perhaps your real problem here is not with [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) but with the structure of the documents contained having no *unique key* in which to access them. That being the case then maybe you should consider altering the structure of the sub-documents in your data to have a reasonable identifier for use in finding the documents you want. This is generally a best practice approach.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But, my problem is that I need to find just some stores, not all. So, if I have two separate collections (stores and advertisements), I'll need: 1) Get all stores according my criteria. 2) For each store, get all advertisements from this store. So if I had 100 stores and each store has 10 advertisements, will be a hundred queries on advertisements collection! Plus loop to iterate! That's why I prefer to have only one collection.

Comment: Not following your logic. You should be able to query for the `store matching` and `advertisement matching` criteria in the one find operation. Perhaps you should expand your question to show a small sample of documents with the criteria you are trying to match rather than just show one. You comments just then are not indicated in th question you are asking.